# c++ diamond inheritance construct only by base constructor

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

[image]

I have trouble to construct my queen class from using the piece, which is the base class, i had virtual my rook and bishop class, to prevent duplicate problem. right now i got the error stated the Rook and Bishop is virtual and it don't have a default constructor.

here my class declartion

```
class Piece
{
public:
  Piece(Colour c, const Position& pos);
  virtual ~Piece();
private:
  Colour piece_colour;
  Position piece_pos;
};
class Bishop: public virtual Piece
{
public:
  Bishop(Colour c, const Position& pos);
  ~Bishop();
};

class Rook: public virtual Piece
{
public:
  Rook(Colour c, const Position& pos);
  ~Rook();
};

#ifdef MSC_VER
class Queen: public virtual Piece, public Bishop, public Rook
#else
class Queen: public Bishop, public Rook
#endif
{
public:
  Queen(Colour c, const Position& pos);
  ~Queen();
};
```

here is my implement

```
Piece::Piece(Colour c, const Position& pos)
:piece_colour{c}, piece_pos{pos}
{

}

Bishop::Bishop(Colour c, const Position& pos)
:Piece(c,pos)
{

}

Rook::Rook(Colour c, const Position& pos)
:Piece(c,pos)
{

}

Queen::Queen(Colour c, const Position& pos)
:Piece(c,pos)
{

}
```

Comment: Queen's constructor has to call Rook's constructor and Bishop's constructor.

Comment: Also, this is an incorrect use of inheritance.  inheritance is supposed to denote "is a" relationship.

Comment: Whilst it might not have occurred to me to derive queen from rook and bishop, I'm not sure I see what the technical objection to this inheritance is. Rook is a piece that moves any number of squares along ranks or files. Bishop is a piece that moves any number of squares diagonally. By those definitions a Queen really "is a" rook and "is a" bishop. Its debatable whether this is an unusual use of inheritance, but incorrect is a strong word. What's actually incorrect here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that when you construct a `Queen` object, that object incorporates a `Rook` object and a `Bishop` object.  Both of those objects also have to be constructed when the `Queen` object is constructed.

As your code is currently written, the compiler will try to call the default constructors `Bishop()` and `Rook()` to instantiate those objects.

But your code does not define the `Bishop()` and `Rook()` constructors - so you get an error telling you the `Bishop` and `Rook` classes don't have default constructors defined.

One way to address your problem would be to define the default constructors `Bishop()` and `Rook()` along with the default constructor `Piece()`...

```
protected:
   Piece::Piece()   { }
   Bishop::Bishop() { }
   Rook::Rook()     { }
```

… if you do that, you'll want to make those constructors `protected` so they can only be called from derived classes.

Another approach would be to change the `Queen` constructor to explicitly call the `Bishop` and `Rook` constructors that you have already defined...

```
Queen::Queen(Colour c, const Position& pos)
   : Bishop(c, pos), Rook(c, pos), Piece(c, pos)
```

If your `Bishop(c, pos)` and `Rook(c, pos)` constructors do real work then this second approach is the only real solution (assuming the real work depends on the Colour and Position parameters passed to them).

Comment: I'd advise the second of these options. Introducing a default constructor for piece involves making a default choice for position and colour. There is no sensible choice so it's better to avoid the default constructor, given this simple alternative.